# Why does System.Configuration show up as lower case in References?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I know this is a silly question but why does why does System.Configuration show up as lower case in References (ie the assembly is named System.configuration.dll). Was this a mistake or a design decision?

Comment: This is happening for me to, but what is weird is that the 'c' is uppercase in one project and lowercase in another project within the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the filename of the code library.  The component name is `System.Configuration`.  Mine is like that as well.  Just the case that they have the filename saved as.

It's not an error, and definitely nothing to worry about.